# Nest.js ConfigService not working in e2e tests (Config validation error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

My .env file includes `NODE_ENV=development` variable, but I get the following error:

● Test suite failed to run

```
Config validation error: "NODE_ENV" must be one of [development, production]

  11 |   imports: [
  12 |     DatabaseModule,
> 13 |     ConfigModule.forRoot({
     |                  ^
  14 |       isGlobal: true,
  15 |       validationSchema,
  16 |       validationOptions: {

  at Function.forRoot (../node_modules/@nestjs/config/dist/config.module.js:75:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../src/app.module.ts:13:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app.e2e-spec.ts:4:1)
```

My test:

```
describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/user (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).post('/user').expect(200);
  });
});
```

My validation file:

```
export default Joi.object({
  NODE_ENV: Joi.string()
    .valid('development', 'production')
    .default('development'),
  ...
});
```

My app.module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema,
      validationOptions: {
        allowUnknown: true,
        abortEarly: false,
      },
    }),
    ...
  ],
```

When I run nest start:dev everything works smoothly, unit tests also run normally

Comment: I believe that `NODE_ENV` is being injected as `"test"` or something like that. And `process.env.` takes precedence over dot env files

Comment: Solved! Tks @MicaelLevi

Answer (score 0):

Jest runs tests with `NODE_ENV=test`, so it's like a different instance of your app. To fix your issue, add `test` as a valid `NODE_ENV` value in your validation schema.